# Visual Studio Code html auto-formatter adding spaces all over the place

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently Visual Studio Code auto HTML formatting seems to be doing some weird adding of spaces.  I've been through all the settings to see if there is some setting that I have set that I shouldn't but I couldn't find anything.  Problem seems to have appeared within the last week.
For example, the following code:

```
<table class="decodeTable" ng-show="mode == '0'">
```

Now has 2 spaces:

```
<table class=" decodeTable " ng-show="mode == '0'">
```

And again:

```
<button ng-click="setOperator(generaldata.operator)">Set Operator</button>
<button ng-click="setOperator(generaldata.operator) ">Set Operator</button>
```

There are loads of examples all through the file.

I only have 3 extensions installed,

- Beautify css/sass/scss/less by michelemelluso
- C/C++ by Microsoft
- sftp by liximomo

It doesn't affect anything other than my git history, but it sure is annoying.

VSCode on windows version:

```
Version 1.22.2
Commit 3aeede733d9a3098f7b4bdc1f66b63b0f48c1ef9
Date 2018-04-12T16:38:45.278Z
Shell 1.7.12
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64
```